# How to read content from rpm file and show file permissions

Tags: linux, files, permissions, rpm

I am able to read content of rpm by using

```
rpm -qlp *.rpm
```

But it shows me the files without permissions. I want it looks like output from 'ls -l' command. How is this possible without extract the package?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `--dump` to extract all the available metadata for files in the package, and post-process that:

```
rpm -qp --dump *.rpm  | awk '{ printf "%7s %8s %8s %8d %s %s\n", $5, $6, $7, $2, strftime("%c", $3), $1 }'
```

Adapting the `strftime()` call, and the mode/permissions output, to mimick `ls`’s behaviour is left as an exercise to the reader.